# MySQL очень тормозит при вставке записей: innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit не помогает

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, производительность

Господа, я некоторое время пытался заставить MySQL делать сравнительно быструю вставку записей в таблицу.

Самое очевидное перебрал: индексы не мешают, сама таблица стоит из двух полей (идентификатор и строка), памяти вроде бы хватает.

Попытки переместить таблицу в память ( ENGINE=memory ) не отражаются на производительности. Скорость сети - не влияет, этот вывод я делаю потому, что при запросах на select производительность на несколько порядков выше.

При этом сервер явно упирается в диск, это видно на следующей картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я тестировал:

1. самое простое - написал хранимую вида

   ```
    CREATE DEFINER=`konst`@`192.168.0.101` PROCEDURE `speed_test1`()
    BEGIN

    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;

    DELETE FROM test_table;

    WHILE i<250 DO
    INSERT INTO test_table (id, name) VALUES (i, 'test_string');
    SET i=i+1;
    END WHILE;

    END
   ```
2. Написал маленькую программу на C++, которая тоже вставляет записи в цикле.

Я решил, что, скорее всего, дело в фиксации транзакций - просиходит запись на диск после каждой вставки.

Тогда я попробовал в файл  /etc/my.cnf дописать в конец строчку

```
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

и перезапустил докер - контейнер с MySQL.

Ничего не изменилось. При innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0 тоже ничего не изменилось.

Вставить больше 20-25 записей в секунду - не удается.

Что еще можно попробовать?

Заранее спасибо за советы.

Comment: А диск-то где расположен и где и как запускается докер?

Comment: Это локальный сервер, 4-х ядерный процессор и 8 гб памяти, обычный "блинчатый" жесткий диск. Докер запускается без каких либо ограничений.

Comment: Запускается-то где? Нативный линукс, виртуальная машина, WSL какой-то версии? Какая файловая система, на которой работает докер? Всё это крайне сильно влияет на производительность (ну и «блинчатный» жесткий диск её тоже не улучшает конечно)

Comment: По словам кажется это что то аппаратное. Сам сервер как бы сидит на битых секторах. И при вставке несколько раз обращается к памяти

Comment: Меняет ли что-нибудь явное открытие и закрытие транзакции? BEGIN - INSERT - INSERT  - INSERT - ... - COMMIT ?  А так-то 25 вставок в секунду на HDD - я бы не сказал, что это "очень тормозит".

Comment: Господа, спасибо большое за внимание к проблеме, но поверьте, это НЕ АППАРАТНОЕ. Я неделю пытаюсь с этим что то сделать ("в бэкграунде"). Хост - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, на ext4. на нём запущен в докере контейнер из имиджа mysql/mysql-server с докерхаба. Когда я первый раз столкнулся с проблемой - я попробовал переустановить контейнер (ну, "выключи и включи заново", вы же понимаете) - и ничего не изменилось. И потом - проблема именно в том, что я пытаюсь mysql-ю сказать "пиши транзакции пореже", там же в заголовке треда про это сказано. Сейчас сделал для очистки совести проверку диска - без бэдов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Господа,
спасибо за отклик,
думаю, что я решил проблему.
Кажется, дело было в том, что mysql писал binlog.
Когда я привел /etc/my.cnf в следующее состояние

```
    [mysqld]
    disable_log_bin
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4096M

    # join_buffer_size = 128M
    # sort_buffer_size = 2M
    # read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M

    skip-host-cache
    skip-name-resolve
    datadir=/var/lib/mysql
    socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    secure-file-priv=/var/lib/mysql-files
    user=mysql

    pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    secure-file-priv = ""
```

то я с легкостью получил около 800 инсертов в секунду. И это - при работе по сети (локалка, 100 Мб). Думаю, что если перейти на 1Gb сеть - получу около 1000 инсертов.

В общем, я думаю, дело во второй строке этого конфига.

Теперь загрузка диска и процессора при массовой вставке выглядит прилично:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Большое спасибо всем, кто откликнулся!